# Shiny conditional variable-columns formatting with formatStyle

Tags: r, shiny

I have a list of dataframes, each with a common column name but other columns may differ. My goal is to format every but the common column as each df is shown in a shiny app.
This is as far as I've gone:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(101)

df1 <- data.frame(id = runif(10), col1 = rnorm(10), col2 = rnorm(10))
df2 <- data.frame(id = runif(10), col1 = rnorm(10), col3 = rnorm(10))
df3 <- data.frame(id = runif(10), col3 = rnorm(10), col4 = rnorm(10))

df <- list(data1 = df1, data2 = df2, data3 = df3)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(3, selectInput('select', 'Choose dataframe: ', choices = c('data1', 'data2', 'data3'),
                          selected = 1)),
    column(9, DTOutput('table'))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  selected <- reactive({
    input$select
  })

  col_names <- c('col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4')

  output$table <- renderDT(
    df[[selected()]] %>% formatStyle(names(.)[names(.) %in% col_names], backgroundColor = 'yellow'), 
    options = list(pageLength = 15))

}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

And here is the error I get in the console:

> Warning: Error in name2int: You specified the columns: col1, col2, but the column names of the data are 
>    [No stack trace available]

[image: Table not rendered]

How can I get formatStyle to work with those variable column names?

Comment: Perhaps wrap with `req`

Comment: Can you elaborate, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider changing it to `datatable`

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  selected <- reactive({
  input$select
  })

  col_names <- c('col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4')

  output$table <- DT::renderDT(

    {dat <- df[[selected()]]
    nm1 <- intersect(names(dat), col_names)

    DT::datatable(dat, options = list(pageLength = 15))   %>%
        formatStyle(nm1, backgroundColor = 'yellow')
    }


  )

}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

-output

[image]

Comment: Much obliged! I didn't realized it before because I had added a DataExplorer::drop_columns(<some_col>) which rendered a dataframe instead of a datatable.